# Share Dialog - Facebook sdk 4.0 Integration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to add a share dialog in my app with the new Facebook SDK but I have a problem when adding the provider in my manifest.

Indeed, i have to add :

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true"/>
```

But for me, i have one App ID per Country (1 Facebook developer app / country).
When I add 2 providers, I have a conflict in Android Studio because of the provider android:name.

Can I put a reference to the string in the "android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}" ? 
Is it possible to do this ?
Or can I declare many provider with the same name ?
Or Can I have one manifest per country ?

Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

1. Have multiple classes that extend FacebookContentProvider (and just name them different names without overriding any methods), and use a different class for every app ID.
2. Build different AndroidManifest.xml files for every country that you have an app ID for, then build and publish different .apk files for each country in the Play Store (since you can filter by countries your app is available for in the Play store).

Comment: Thxs, I will try the first one.

Like this, is it true? :

<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1111" android:name="mypackage.FacebookContentProviderEn" android:exported="true"/>

<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider2222" android:name="mypackage.FacebookContentProviderFr" android:exported="true"/>

Thanks